# Mantener un servicio Android siempre vivo

Tags: android

Llevo intentando esto mucho tiempo, buscando documentación y diferentes preguntas en stackoverflow pero no he dado con la clave.

Necesito lanzar un servicio que no muera al cerrar la APP por completo.

He probado

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

con el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Al lanzarlo:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock cpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
cpuWakeLock.acquire();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebViewService.class);
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Y un sin fín de códigos que no ha dado resultado.. es posible?

Algún consejo? Gracias!

Comment: Podrías agregar un poco más de código, usas startForeground()?

Comment: @Jorgesys acabo de añadir el activity cuando lo lanza, no no lo uso, tu has conseguido hacerlo? es realmente posible o es una ilusión? jaja

Comment: Claro que es posible!, pero prefiero realizarlo mediante un  BroadCastReciever, agrego información sobre las 2 opciones.

Comment: @Jorgesys estás de acuerdo con la respuesta de Juan Pablo? hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo? gracias por tus comentarios

Comment: Bueno lo que realiza es solo iniciar en onCreate() el servicio, lo que tu deseas es tenerlo siempre vivo. Estoy terminando mi respuesta. :P

Comment: La idea es que el servicio no se apaga cuando la app se cierre o quieres prevenir desde el servicio también que el dispositivo se suspende?

Comment: @StefanNolde el objetivo es que no se apague cuando la app se cierra totalmente, on destroy del application

Comment: Mirate la documentación oficial de armar un servicio hay una propiedad que puede serte de utilidad isolatedProcess=true tambien prueba con el tuto siguiente: http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Comment: echa un ojo a la pregunta que hice que es similar a la tuya: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/73038/30364

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tengo implementado algo similar en una aplicación propia que lo que hace es levantar el servicio cada vez que este muere y también cuando se reinicia el dispositivo:

Clase que extiende BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
         ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx, MyService.class));

    }

}
```

En mi servicio mismo:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    .....

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    .....

}
```

En el AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcast">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Edit:
El servicio se inicia en el onCreate de mi MainActivity:

```
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){ //método que determina si el servicio ya está corriendo o no
        serv = new Intent(ctx,MyService.class); //serv de tipo Intent
        ctx.startService(serv); //ctx de tipo Context
        Log.d("App", "Service started");
    } else {
        Log.d("App", "Service already running");
    }
```

Comment: gracias, lo estoy probando, podrías poner el código donde lanzas el broadcast? al poner tal cual lo que has puesto nunca entra en el oncreate del servicio

Comment: Edité la respuesta mostrando donde y cómo se inicia el servicio

Comment: Gracias está funcionando, lo probaré mañana con un Android 6 y con algún dispositivo Samsung de los que matan servicios para ahorrar energía a ver si sigue así! Gracias

Comment: @pcg26 Por las dudas, el BroadcastReceiver es levantado por el tag **<receiver>** que se encuentra en el manifest. No hay necesidad de hacer un register mediante código Java.

Comment: mmm no entiendo que quieres decir

Comment: El Receiver se declara e inicia estáticamente con el tag **<receiver>** que se encuentra en el manifest, como se menciona [aquí](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) y [aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)

Comment: Una pregunta, esta opción también vale para cuando el usuario le da a Forzar Detención?

Comment: En el método que utilizas para determinar si el servicio esta corriendo o no. De donde sale el isMyServiceRunning?, es la única parte que no me queda clara.

Comment: Cómo haces el isMyServiceRunning?

Answer (score 6):

Para mantener un servicio al cerrar la aplicación, usa `START_STICKY` en `onStartCommand()`

De acuerdo a tu código veo que enlazas un servicio por lo cual lo que estas realizando es que tu Activity interactua con el servicio:

```
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

En este caso lo que podrías es usar un servicio en Primer Plano ([Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)), lo cual se realiza mediante el método [startForeground()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);

startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

---

La opción que realizo regularmente mediante un BroadcastReceiver es la siguiente, puedes tomar este articulo como ejemplo:

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.mx/2013/05/how-to-make-android-service-unstoppable.html

1) registra el servicio al iniciar tu dispositivo, con esto no tienes que abrir la aplicación para que inicie:

```
<receiver android:name="ReceiverCall" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.stackoveflow.myservicio" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2) Agregar en la clase `BroadcastReceiver`  código para reiniciar el servicio de nuevamente.

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Servicio", "El servicio se detuvo");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServiceTest.class));;
    }

}
```

3) Crear la clase del Servicio Android y en `onDestroy()` implementar iniciar el servicio y **definir `return START_STICKY` en `onStartCommand()`** para que el servicio siga funcionando después de cerrar la aplicación.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    .....

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.stackoveflow.myservicio");
        intent.putExtra("yourvalue", "torestore");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Es posible que algún dispositivo (tipo Xiaomis...) no permitan servicios cuando la app muere? y respecto a tu respuesta, cuando muere guardar un valor a restaurar, podrías indicar como recuperarlo? Gracias!

Comment: Estoy probando tu código pero no me entra en el oncreate al igual que me pasó con el código de Juan Pablo hasta poner la inicialización en el activity

Comment: al declarar esto en tu Manifest.xml <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> el broadcastreceiver estara activo cuando se encienda el dispositivo! en cuanto al valor a restaurar, puedes guardar valores segun el estatus en preferencias.

Comment: @pcg26 cual código el del Broadcast receiver? en el artículo viene un ejemplo para descargar.

Comment: pero si no hace falta abrir la app, entonces no haría falta usar   startService(new Intent(this, ServiceTest.class)) en el main activity no? respecto a restricciones de móviles tipo Xiaomi que no ejecuten servicios en background sabes algo?

Comment: ahh cuando se activa el BroadcastReceiver se manda llamar onReceive por lo tanto también startService() , si te refieres al contexto, this en realidad es el servicio, por lo tanto no necesita un MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

@Andress Blend para quienes necesiten el método isMyServiceRunning.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
    if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```