# Ejecutar un método cada X minutos

Tags: java, android

he visto varias preguntas sobre cómo ejecutar un método cada X minutos, sin embargo tengo una duda general sobre el funcionamiento del objeto Timer o Handler.

Handler:

```
final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //llama método a ejecutarse cada 10 segundos

        handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
    }
}, EXECUTION_TIME);
```

Timer:

```
private Timer temporizador;
private TimerTask tarea;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private void IniciarTemporizador(){
    temporizador = new Timer();
    tarea = new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
          handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run(){
                //tu código aqui
             }
          });
       }
    };
    temporizador.schedule(tarea, tiempo_delay, tiempo_bucle);
}
```

[Fuente de los códigos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/77227/llamar-al-m%C3%A9todo-de-un-thread-cada-x-tiempo)

La duda que me surge es: ¿si el usuario cierra la aplicación completamente, se realiza la llamada al método?. 
Supongamos que el usuario abre el listado de aplicaciones recientes y desliza la aplicación hacía la derecha| arriba |o como sea en cada dispositivo. ¿Se llegará a realizar la llamada?.

En el caso de no ser así, ¿qué podría hacer para que el método se llamase a pesar de que el usuario fuerce el cierre de la aplicación?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Recuerda que las preguntas basadas en opiniones son cerradas revisar [ask], obtén reputación para que preguntes en el [chat]. Te comento que al cerrar la aplicación un Handler o Timer dejan de funcionar, lo que debes realizar es un servicio para que cuando se cierre la aplicación este continué realizando el proceso cada x tiempo , revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48197/mantener-un-servicio-android-siempre-vivo